# How do I fix "some language have errors" in Google Play?

Tags: android

I am in the process of uploading my Android app to the Play Store. I'm filling out the listing, but I see "some languages have errors". Now, my app does have several language variations (9 languages). BUT....what does that error mean?

I've filled in all the areas, none show any problems. How can a supposedly reputable company like Google permit such an unaddressable error occur in its Play Listing?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, deleted everything (it wasn't all that much) and started over. No errors now!

Comment: Opps. Still some weird issues. Really Play is amateur hour.